# Reset default scale ARCore Transformable Node

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I am using an ArFragment and I'm trying to change the scale of a TransformableNode which is the child of an AnchorNode programatically. I'm using the following code:

```
ar_scaleTest_button.setOnClickListener {

    for(node in fragment!!.arSceneView.scene.children) {
        if(node.children.size != 0) {
            val transNode = node.children[0] as TransformableNode

            if(transNode.isSelected) {
                Toast.makeText(it.context, 
                               "Scale was: "+transNode.localScale.toString(), 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                transNode.localScale = Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After debugging I realized the method being executed was setLocalScale() in Node class, but it was receiving a null value instead of the Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f). I checked this by placing a breakpoint in the second line following method, which never reaches:

```
public void setLocalScale(Vector3 var1) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(var1, "Parameter \"scale\" was null.");
    this.localScale.set(var1);
    this.applyTransformUpdateRecursively();
}
```

Are we setting the scale correctly? Is there another way to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your title and description seem different. Is all you want to do is reset the scale of AR object?

Comment: and also, are you using sceneform?

Comment: Yes, I am using sceneform and I want a button to reset the scale of the selected model back to 1. I managed to make it work in a quite unpleasant way by creating a new TransformableNode with the same localPosition, localRotation and renderable properties as the original one, adding it to the AnchorNode parent and deleting the old one. Not very aesthetic but it does the trick. Ofc I would love to hear a better way

Comment: Just use, `node.setWorldScale(Vector3.one());`

Comment: Have you resolved it ?

Comment: It was a bottleneck problem so I quick fixed it by erasing previous node and creating a new one. There must be a better way but I will try when I have more time